# What does this code do?

Tags: javascript, facebook

Moaning about the lack of a dislike button is all the rage on Facebook at the moment and various groups have sprung up offering a dislike button, but only after you've invited x amount of your friends.

One of the more (possibly devious?) groups requires you to run Javascript as part of the joining process. I haven't ever done web coding so I'm wondering if someone can tell me what the following code does?

```
javascript:elms=document.getElementById('friends').getElementsByTagName('li');
for(var fid in elms){
     if(typeof elms[fid] === 'object'){
          fs.click(elms[fid]);
     }
}
```

The link to the group is here: [|►OFFICIAL Dislike Button™ is Finally Here◄| Add it Now, it ACTUALLY WORKS!](http://www.facebook.com/group.php?v=info&ref=nf&gid=253735965777). The code is listed under the 3 steps in the recent news section.

Comment: Annoy everybody on your friends list about the group?

Comment: No I think they actually have to join, but I just ignore this type of group. The only group of that type I've joined is "An Arbitrary Number of People Demanding That Some Sort Of Action Be Taken". For obvious reasons ;)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
// Find the Element in the webpage that has the ID "friends", which is the list of your friends ;-)
javascript:elms=document.getElementById('friends').getElementsByTagName('li'); 
// Iterate over every friend in the list
for(var fid in elms){ 
     // just a validation
     if(typeof elms[fid] === 'object'){ 
          // Click on the invite to Group button
          fs.click(elms[fid]); 
     } 
}
```

Basically, this code causes a **group invitation for all of your friends** ;-)

Answer (score -1):

This will fetch all the li elements in the element with the id 'friends' and then loop through them and if it's an 'object' perform fs.click(elms[fid])

Comment: Translation: invites all your friends to the group.

Comment: -1 This doesn't really say what the code does, anyone with enough experience in programming could have gleamed this from the code.

Comment: So I do say what the code does, but not what you really wanted.. great.. next time I will try to read your mind before answering